# Chef client provisioner unable to authenticate with chef server

Tags: terraform

I have a terraform file with the following resource

```
provisioner "chef" {  
    environment     = "terraform"    
    run_list        = ["cookbook::recipe"]
    node_name       = "chefclient1"    
    server_url      = "https://1.2.3.4/organizations/terraform"
    recreate_client = true
    user_name       = "my_username"
    user_key        = "${file("chefuser.pem")}"
    version         = "12.4.1"
    ssl_verify_mode = "verify_none"
    connection {
        user = "ubuntu"
        private_key = "${file("test.pem")}"
        agent = "false" 
        timeout = "30s"
    }
  }
```

When executed I keep getting

```
aws_instance.chefclient (chef): ERROR: Failed to authenticate to https://52.23.2
43.121/organizations/terraform/ as my_username with key /etc/chef/my_username.pem
aws_instance.chefclient (chef): Response:  Invalid signature for user or client
'akajain'
```

I am confused for user_key here. Is this the .pem file created when creating the chef user using

```
chef-server-ctl user-create test test me test@gmail.com 'root123' --filename /tmp/chefuser.pem
```

or the .pem file organatiosation validator file created while running

```
chef-server-ctl org-create terraform 'Terraform Chef Inc' --association_user test --filename terraform-validator.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

Username.pem will be present in your chefrepo/.chef folder. If you are facing issue try resetting user key and download new key. It worked for me.